# CSS: How to apply a bunch of classes instead of other classes, when the dark class is active?

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm styling the `.mdx` files in my Next.js app with TailwindCSS and Prism.

I have a dark mode toggle that adds the "dark" class to the classes of the `<html />` tag on my side when the dark mode is toggled on.

```html
<html class="h-full antialiased"><!-- rest of the html document --></html>
```

vs.

```html
<html class="h-full antialiased dark"><!-- rest of the html document --></html>
```

Now I have a bunch of styles that I only want to apply when the dark mode is toggled on.

E.g., when the light mode is activated and the `<html />` tag lacks the "dark" class, these styles should apply (and the dark modes' should NOT).

```css
pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
code[class*="language-"]::selection,
code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.99);
}

.token.comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.cdata {
  color: rgb(152, 159, 177);
}

.token.punctuation {
  color: rgb(153, 76, 195);
}
```

When the `<html />` tag has the "dark" class, these styles should apply (and the ones from the light mode should NOT).

```css
pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
code[class*="language-"]::selection,
code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(29, 59, 83, 0.99);
}

.token.comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.cdata {
  color: rgb(99, 119, 119);
}

.token.punctuation {
  color: rgb(199, 146, 234);
}
```

**Note:** My actual stylesheet has waaayyy more classes.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

I tried prefixing every class with `.dark`, which works, but is pretty tedious because you have to add it to every class.

```css
.dark .token.punctuation {
  color: rgb(199, 146, 234);
}
```

I also tried nesting, which didn't work neither:

```css
.dark {
  pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
  pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
  code[class*="language-"]::selection,
  code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: rgba(29, 59, 83, 0.99);
  }

  .token.comment,
  .token.prolog,
  .token.cdata {
    color: rgb(99, 119, 119);
  }

  .token.punctuation {
    color: rgb(199, 146, 234);
  }
}
```

##### Note 1:

I'm toggling the dark mode based on a script in my `_document.tsx`:

```
import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

const modeScript = `
  const darkModeMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  updateMode();
  darkModeMediaQuery.addEventListener('change', updateModeWithoutTransitions);
  window.addEventListener('storage', updateModeWithoutTransitions);

  function updateMode() {
    const isSystemDarkMode = darkModeMediaQuery.matches;
    const isDarkMode =
      window.localStorage.isDarkMode === 'true' ||
      (!('isDarkMode' in window.localStorage) && isSystemDarkMode);

    if (isDarkMode) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
    }

    if (isDarkMode === isSystemDarkMode) {
      delete window.localStorage.isDarkMode;
    }
  }

  function disableTransitionsTemporarily() {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('[&_*]:!transition-none');
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('[&_*]:!transition-none');
    }, 0);
  }

  function updateModeWithoutTransitions() {
    disableTransitionsTemporarily();
    updateMode();
  }
`;

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html className="h-full antialiased" lang="en">
      <Head>
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: modeScript }} />
// ...
```

##### Note 2:

I'm importing the styles in my `pages/_app.tsx` file.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import './prism.css';
```

And then:

```
// in _app.tsx
import '~/styles/globals.css';
```

Maybe there is a way based on the TypeScript to import the correct CSS file? But I couldn't make this approach work either.

Comment: That would be a perfect use case for the css variables. Have you thought about that ?